# How to replace all other character except alphabets, number and "hyphen" in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g

I have sql query and want to replace all characters except hyphen(-) , alphabets and numbers.
How can I do that in sql query?

Answer (score 2):

You can represent non hyphen or alphanumeric characters by the class:

```
[^\-a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Then use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove these characters from your column:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (col, '[^\-a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score -2):

This would remove all the `alphabets` and `numbers` from the input string and will leave `'-'`.

```
SELECT 'Rajkakla-53535-' As Strng, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE ('Rajkakla-53535-', '[A-Za-z]',''), '[0-9]','') As No_Alphnum
FROM dual;
```

Or you can use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('Rajkakla-53535-', '[a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
FROM dual;
```